# Intuition behind Stationarity in Delayed Renewal Processes

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I was going through excess life and renewal processes in my notes when I came across a proposition in my notes that said that given a delayed renewal process X with independant interarrival times $Z_{n}$ for n > 0 with probability distribution f, and $Z_{0}$ having a distribution $f_{0}(x)$, then X has stationary increments.

From earlier context in the notes, I believe $f_{0}$ is referring to the aysmptotic distribution of the residual time of f, but its not presented very clearly.

I always thought it was was only very special distributions that had stationary distributions, but this proposition suggests more general processes can have stationary increments which doesn't seem very natural to me?